# Filtering User Input

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, input

I've read quite a few q&a's on filtering user input here, but most of the time the answer is that it depends on what you're doing. Here's what I'm doing:

Data submitted via a form that will be used in a MySQL query:

```
function clean($field, $link)
{
    return mysql_real_escape_string($field, $link);
}
```

Data submitted via a form that will be displayed back on the HTML/PHP page or in an email:

```
function output_html($value)
{
    return stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($value));
}
```

Data displayed from database:

```
function output_db($value)
{
    return stripslashes($value);
}
```

Is this sufficient for my needs? Is there something I'm not considering?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about application security, i.e. SQL injection?

Comment: @robert-harvey SQL injection and also adding code permantely to my pages via JS, etc

Comment: The `output_db` indicates that you are doing it wrong. If you correctly escape your content, and don't have superflous magic_quotes enabled, then there's no need for stripslashes() AFTER the database query. http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` when inserting strings into SQL queries, no matter where the input comes from.

Use `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()` when inserting strings into HTML code, no matter where the input comes from.

Use `urlencode()` when inserting values into the query string of a URL, no matter where the values come from.

If this data comes from the user, then you should definitely do these things because there is the chance that the user is trying to do bad things.  But security aside--what if you want to insert a legitimate string into a SQL query and the string just happens to have a single quote character in it?  You still must escape it.

Comment: This may sound like a silly ques but just to clarify, does the urlencode() apply to a query string which is generated automatically by a form? the values are hardcoded into the form so i'm guessing nothing needs to be done but i just wanted to clarify. thanks <form action="search.php" method="get"><input id="search_content" placeholder="Search" type="text" name="query" size="40" value="" action="" columns="2" autocomplete="off" delay="1500"><button id="submit_search" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button><input type="hidden" name="search" value="1"></form>

Comment: @Sarah Good question.  Values that are submitted using a `<form>` are automatically URL-encoded by the browser.  In your form, for example, the "search_content" textbox's value will be URL-encoded by the browser when the user clicks the submit button.

Answer (score 2):

I would really look into using something like PDO if you are starting out. You will eventually want to migrate that way, so why not start now.

PDO will cleanse your input automatically, which is great. It will also use prepare() statements, so you are guaranteed a single query, which prevents someone attacking with a "; DROP TABLE xxx;" or such.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 2):

When you insert data into a SQL database, you need to escape it in order to prevent SQL injections, and `mysql_real_escape_string()` is the right thing to use for that in mysql. You have to remember to use that for everything, though, so it's error-prone. You should instead be using something like PDO, which automatically escapes every incoming value.

Data coming out of a database does not usually need any special treatment (ie. unescaping). I don't know what you're trying to do with `stripslashes()` there. If it's for removing magic quotes that PHP inserted, you should be doing that where you extract user-provided values from GET/POST/etc. (or disable magic quotes completely, if you can, and don't have any other software that relies on it)

Data going out to html needs to be escaped to prevent XSS. `htmlspecialchars()` is the right function for that. Again, I don't know what you're trying to use `stripslashes()` for. And again, you need to remember to escape every value, which is error-prone. You should at least consider the benefits of using a templating engine or something else that automatically escapes all values going to html.

Comment: Hi thanks for this information :) I just wanted to clarify, is htmlspecialchars() the only security treatment I need to do on the variables which are outputting to html? and when you say error-prone do you mean it may not work sometimes and therefore not be 100% secure? and what templating engines are there available do you know?thanks, sarah

Comment: @Sarah: It's the only thing you need for data inside elements. (of course, if you put arbitrary user content inside a script element, you're still screwed) What I mean by error-prone is that it's easy to forget to use it everywhere, and if you forget it even in one place, you're screwed. If you need to put user-defined content to attributes (eg. href), you need to do more than that, though, since a malicious user could input eg. `javascript:whatever`. Eg. for href, you'll probably want to whitelist some allowed protocols only, because browsers allow various variations of "javascript:" to work.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. can i ask you, in terms of the href attribute.. is that only in the case where it is user defined?.. In my project i am retrieving json data from facebook and working with that data in php, inserting this data to href attributes and other elements. however in this case it is all coming from facebook, nothing comes from the user. will i need to perform security measures on this data before inserting it to my html or would it be safe?.. thanks...

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability, I'd recommend using mysqli instead of mysql, and utilize prepared statements:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$city = "Amersfoort";

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($district);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

    /* close statement */
   $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

This provides basic type checking and does escaping for you. I would not recommend `stripslashes` on outputting db data because:

1. DB data can have slashes in them
2. The database unescapes for you anyways

With regards to showing HTML, there is also `htmlstriptags` which can strip out people trying to be cute with  tags and the like.

Answer (score 0):

i will recommend you to use the filters introduced in php 5.2 they are great and saves you lots of lines of validation and sanatization of data. check here

[filter_input](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)