# PHP MySQL Variable Filter - "AND" Acting Like "OR"

Tags: php, mysql, variables, filter

Is there a simpler method to using url variables to filter mysql results? I wrote the following code and it works to a degree and I know there has to be a simpler method, but I'm not sure where to start. I'd rather replace this one since it only half works.

```
$start=0;
$limit=3;

if(isset($_GET['pg']))
{
$pg=$_GET['pg'];
$start=($pg-1)*$limit;
}
else { 
$pg = 1;
}
$sql = mysql_query($query);
if(isset($_GET['signage'])) {
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM pilotOperators WHERE signage='1' LIMIT $start, $limit");
}
elseif(isset($_GET['certifications'])) {
    $certification = $_GET['certifications'];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM pilotOperators WHERE certifications='$certification' LIMIT $start, $limit");
}
elseif(isset($_GET['state'])) {
    $state = $_GET['state'];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM pilotOperators WHERE state='$state' LIMIT $start, $limit");
}
elseif(isset($_GET['certifications'], $_GET['signage'])) {
    $certification = $_GET['certifications'];
    $signage = $_GET['signage'];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM pilotOperators WHERE signage='$signage' AND certifications='$certification' LIMIT $start, $limit");
}
elseif(isset($_GET['certifications'], $_GET['signage'], $_GET['state'])) {
    $certification = $_GET['certifications'];
    $signage = $_GET['signage'];
    $state = $_GET['state'];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM pilotOperators WHERE signage='$signage' AND certifications='$certification' AND state='$state' LIMIT $start, $limit");
}
else {
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM pilotOperators LIMIT $start, $limit");
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "\n <table border='0' class='resultTable' width='75%'> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td width='120px'>ID: </td> \n";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td>Name: </td> \n";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td>Phone: </td> \n";
echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td>Alt. Phone: </td> \n";
echo "<td>" . $row['alt_phone'] . "</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td>Fax: </td> \n";
echo "<td>" . $row['fax'] . "</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td>Email: </td> \n";
echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td>Website: </td> \n";
echo "<td><a href='" . $row['website'] . "' target='_blank'>" .  $row['website'] . "</a></td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td>City: </td> \n";
echo "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td>State: </td> \n";
echo "<td>" . $row['state'] . "</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td>Certifications: </td> \n";
echo "<td>" . $row['certifications'] . "</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "<tr> \n";
echo "<td>Top Sign: </td> \n";
echo "<td>";
if($row['signage'] = 1) {
 echo "Has Top Sign";
}
else {
 echo "Top Sign Not Listed";
}
echo "</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
echo "</table> \n\n";
}
$rows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM pilotOperators"));
$total=ceil($rows/$limit);
echo "<div id='paginationLinks'> \n";
if($pg>1)
{
echo "<a href='?pg=".($pg-1)."' class='paginationButton'>PREVIOUS</a> \n";
}
if($pg!=$total)
{
echo "<a href='?pg=".($pg+1)."' class='paginationButton'>NEXT</a> \n";
}

echo "<ul class='page'> \n";
 for($i=1;$i<=$total;$i++)
{
if($i==$pg) { echo "<li class='current'>".$i."</li> \n"; }

else { echo "<li><a href='?id=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li> \n"; }
}
echo "</ul> \n";
echo "</div> \n";
mysqli_close($con);
```

When I said that this code kinda works allow me to explain. When I have multiple variables in my url(I.E. ?signage=VALUE&certifications=VALUE) the code acts like it has OR in place of AND.

Like This:  $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM pilotOperators WHERE signage='$signage' OR certifications='$certification' LIMIT $start, $limit");

Instead Of This:  $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM pilotOperators WHERE signage='$signage' AND certifications='$certification' LIMIT $start, $limit");

If my URL contains the following &signage=1&certifications=washington it is not only showing me results that have both of those, but it is showing me results of people with Washington certifications OR where signage=1.

I don't have many variables that will be passed. It should only be 3, but my method just seems complicated.

What can I do to make this simpler and why does my AND act like OR when attempting to filter the results.

Comment: I would highly recommend validating user input in some manner. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966961/filtering-user-input and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php

Comment: What happens when you try to run these queries directly against MySQL (using MySQL workbench or something similar)

Comment: The variables are all passed by checkboxes and select options. No worry about user input unless they edit the URL lol. I'll look into it though as I do have other forms I need to validate as well.

Comment: `The variables are all passed by checkboxes and select options` Doesn't mean someone can't submit the the data independent of the form (auto or manual submission by changing the URL)

Comment: Maximus it does exactly as I said. It DOES filter the results BUT it basically ignores the AND conditions and acts like they say "OR" pulling results that have part of the parameters and not all.

Comment: I'm looking into those links you sent.

Comment: Don't know if it helps, but maybe placing the WHERE clause between brackets could solve your problem: `... WHERE ( ... AND .. ) LIMIT ..`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q:** What can I do to make this simpler?

**A:** You could do something like the following, to conditionally append a predicate to the SQL statement, and defer running the statement until it's fully built. It looks like you only need to run one SQL statement, so there only needs to be one call to `mysqli_query`. Populate a variable to contain populate with the SQL text, and have `mysqli_query` reference the variable.

NOTE: Any potentially unsafe values *must* be properly escaped to thwart SQL Injection vulnerabilities. (Note the use of the `mysqli_real_escape_string` function around *every* value that's being included in the SQL text.)

For example:

```
# start of SQL statement
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pilotOperators WHERE 1=1";

# append condition for signage (if required)
if(isset($_GET['signage'])) {
   $sql .= " AND signage='1'";
}

# append condition for certifications (if required)
if(isset($_GET['certifications'])) { 
   $certification = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['certifications']);
   $sql .= " AND certifications='$certification'"
}

# append condition for state (if required)
if(isset($_GET['state'])) {
   $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['state']);
   $sql .= " AND state='$state'";
}


# append ORDER BY and LIMIT 
$sql .= " ORDER BY 1,2,3";
$sql .= " LIMIT " . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$start) 
            . "," . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$limit);

#echo "SQL=" . $sql; // for debugging

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

I've also added an ORDER BY clause so the rows will be returned in a deterministic sequence; replace the positional references to the columns you want.

The `WHERE 1=1` is a dummy placeholder, that will always evaluate to TRUE. The purpose of that is so that any subsequent predicates can be added with an `AND` and we don't need to muck with figuring out whether this is the first predicate being added, and we need to use `WHERE` instead of `AND`.

The leading space in each part that's being appended is important. (I just find it easier to handle that as a leading character, rather than remembering to add it at the end, but you could have the space at the end of each part instead).

---

**Q:** Why is my AND acting like OR?

**A:** It's not, you're never getting to a statement that has an `AND` in it. If "certifications" is set, you're executing a SQL statement that contains only a predicate on the `certifications` column. You never reach the `elseif` for "certifications" and "state" both being set.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

There's an error in the code above, a missing semicolon (statement terminator) is missing from one line:

```
   $sql .= " AND certifications='$certification'" ;
                                                  ^
```

---

The **`.=`** operator appends the value on the right to the current value of the variable on the left.  That is, this statement

```
$x .= "foo";
```

does the same thing as this statement.

```
$x = $x . "foo";
```

---

The variables `$certification` and `$state` aren't really necessary. You could remove these two lines:

```
   $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['state']);
   $sql .= " AND state='$state'";
```

and replace it with this:

```
   $sql .= " AND state='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['state']) . "'";
```

But breaking that into two separate lines does make it easier to debug and spot mistakes, easy to add an `echo` or `var_dump` for debugging...

```
   $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['state']);
   echo "state=" . $state ;
   var_dump($state);
   $sql .= " AND state='$state'";
```

Comment: I think I understand a bit better now. So help me understand your code a bit better? The one you posted above will work fully or will I need to add more if statements for the multiple variables? I'm kinda new to working with these types of things. I noticed your using .=(period equals). What does that do? Thanks.

Comment: @JesseElser; The dot equals (**`.=`**) operator (in PHP) appends the value specified on the right side to the current value of the variable on the left side. This: **`$x .= "foo";`** does the same thing as **`$x = $x . "foo";`**

Comment: I used most of your answer. It wasn't fully working(something in the certification area was causing a fatal error) but I did use a modified version that I wrote based off of yours. I really appreciate the help :)

Comment: @JesseElser: there's a semicolon missing on a line in my example code. `$sql .= " AND certifications='$certification'"`... that statement needs to be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: I was trying to find what was wrong lol I always overlook the most simple. I ended up copying and pasting the state one and modifying the wording back to certifications. I also removed the "ORDER" for now until I add a timestamp or something because I do plan on showing newer results first.

Answer (score 1):

That is not best thing you should really do, but just like an idea:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM pilotOperators ';

$filters = array('signage', 'certifications', 'state');

$where = false;
foreach($filters as $filter) {
     if (isset($_GET[$filter])) {
         $filter_val = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET[$filter]);
         if (! $where ) {
           $where = true;
           $query .= ' WHERE '.$filter.'= "'.$filter_val.'"';
         } else {
           $query .= ' AND '.$filter.'= "'.$filter_val.'"';  
         }
     }
}

$query .= " LIMIT $start, $limit";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

**EDIT 1** Ignore some values of filter

```
$filters = array('signage', 'certifications', 'state');

$filters_ignore_value = array('state'=>'Select State');

$where = false;
foreach($filters as $filter) {
     if (isset($_GET[$filter])) {
         $filter_val = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET[$filter]);
         if (isset($filters_ignore_value[$filter] && $filters_ignore_value[$filter] == $filter_val) {
             continue;
         }
         if (! $where ) {
           $where = true;
           $query .= ' WHERE '.$filter.'= "'.$filter_val.'"';
         } else {
           $query .= ' AND '.$filter.'= "'.$filter_val.'"';  
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: When it comes to the different $query I have a question. How does it combine each of those to build the full list? Is that what the .= is for(with the period?)

Comment: I don't understand your question. there is just one variable `$query`. And `.=` is just concatenation operator for the strings. So I just loop through the filters array and check if current filter exists in `$_GET` if it is exists, I check if  `WHERE` clause already started. If it is not started yet  I start it with `WHERE filter = filter`, if it is already started I just add new filter to the end with `AND filter = filter`. So what are you asking about?

Comment: I meant if the URL has multiple variables in it. ?Variable1=VALUE&Variable2=value

Comment: Did you try my solution? in my answer I expect that developer controls the list of accepted filters: so it is preset in $filters. if you need more - you add them into array. User on other side can use or not use accepted filters in incoming request url, that is why we need to check if if `isset($_GET[])`

Comment: Yep. Not getting any results. I've tried all 3 filters.

Comment: not getting any? even if there is no any pararmeters in url??

Comment: show me what you are doing with that `$result` variable to see that there is no results?

Comment: Updated my question with my full code. It also includes a small pagination script. Your code works  until there are  parameters in the url.

Comment: *until there are parameters* ? so my code works? and it is not working if there is no parameters in http request???

Comment: it loads every result BUT when I do try to filter it, nothing appears.

Comment: Give me an example of your url request please, and sample of data in table you have

Comment: I got it working. Now the issue is back on my code. When I filter it by states, the state is chosen from a select option dropdown. I have an option that says <option>Select State</option>. I did not give it a value so that "state" would not be in the URL. But when I submit my form using that option I get the following in my url ?state=Select+State. How can I make it to where if it is on "Select State" then no ?state parameter gets passed to the url?

Comment: Yours worked pretty good but a seperate answer posted helped me a bit more. I really appreciate your efforts and I will be using yours at a later point as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

> When I have multiple variables in my url(I.E. ?signage=VALUE&certifications=VALUE) the code acts like it has OR in place of AND

Take the example of `signage` AND `certifications` being set: the first if clause will evaluate to true, resulting in that query being executed regardless of whether `certifications` is set. You might consider re-ordering the if/elseif. For instance:

```
//check for all
if(isset($_GET['certifications'], $_GET['signage'], $_GET['state'])) {

}elseif (isset($_GET['certifications'], $_GET['signage'])){

}elseif (){

}
```

Alternatively, as suggested in another answer, build your query up by checking each requisite parameter

Comment: So basically the more clauses to look for the higher on the list. I'll give this a try.

Is there an easier way to accomplish what I am doing? I just seem to be going down a complicated path compared to an easy one.

Comment: `Is there an easier way to accomplish what I am doing` Easy is relative, but you can build the query as suggested by @spencer7593